# Excel - How can I count unique emails per hourly interval per employee?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to count unique emails that every employee received per interval. I'm using FREQUENCY and MATCH but I'm getting incorrect outputs. Please see the sample table below. Employee A gets 1 email at 08:00, 1 new email at 09:00 and so on. Thanks!

[image: sample]

Comment: If you have the Office 365: `=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,C:C="A"))`

Comment: unfortunately, we still use 2013 :( thanks though!

Comment: What is the logic of deciding whether an email received at a certain hour is unique?

Comment: i am basing it on the subject line, for example on the 9am interval, out of the 3 emails that employee A - there are 2 different emails ACH and ACHH

Comment: @Mrcvz Why are you not counting email **Follow Up**?

Comment: ah that was actually just an example, i still need to count the email Follow Up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Pivot Table.

- In the Pivot Table Create dialog, select the option to `Add this data to Data Model`

  - If you do that, `Distinct Count` will appear as an option under the Value Field settings.
- Drag Time and Employee to the Rows area
- Drag Emails to the Values area, and select `Distinct Count` in the Value Field Settings.
- Format to taste.

  - I chose `Show in Tabular Form` and `Repeat all Item Labels`

**Original Data**

[image]

**Pivot with Rows Order:**  `Time | Employee`

[image]

**Pivot with Rows Order:**  `Employee | Time`

[image]

Comment: thanks for this! i think this would be the easiest way to do this - i never knew it was this option i need to check

Comment: @Mrcvz It is certainly not a well documented feature.  I'd been using Excel for many years before stumbling across it.

Comment: i have a follow up on this, for employee A - he received the ACH emails specifically at the 8 and 9am intervals, how can i disregard counting the one at the 9am interval? reason for this is that it is the same email he got from 8am. if i were to do it manually, employee A received 1 unique email at 8am, 2 at 9am (as the other ACH is actually ACHH for distinction that it is a new email)

Comment: @Mrcvz How do you know, if an email is logged in at different times, if it is a new email or a duplicate?  If different emails to the same person will always have a slight difference in the Email column, then, before creating the Pivot Table, select the Email and Employee columns and use the `Remove Duplicates` tool.

Comment: @Mrcvz That should read "select the entire table, but just check off the email and employee columns" in the Remove Duplicates Dialog.

Comment: thanks ron! ill play around with it and will let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can try following formula:

```
=1/SUMPRODUCT((C2=$C$2:$C$23)*(A2=$A$2:$A$23)*(B2=$B$2:$B$23))
```

In your sample all emails per hour/employee was unique so I changed one at 9:00/A

[image]